# WebApi not finding controllers when they extend a custom base class

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I have a solution with 2 projects. The first is a class library that has my controller. The second is a self hosted webapi app that has a reference to the DLL for the first project. If my comtrlller inherits from ApiController, it will load fine. If I have the controller inherit from another base class in another library (that then inherits ApiController), it doesn't find the controller. I am not getting any reference version warnings or exceptions. I'm at a loss.

Comment: How do you configure the routes. convention-based or attribute based?

Comment: Attribute routing

Comment: Then the mapping call needs to be done in the external dll. expose a method in that project that takes in the HttpConfiguration and call the map attribute routes extension method.

Comment: Update question with a [mcve] of one of the controllers and how you configure the routes.